# Dynamic widgets

Tags: widgets

In wordpress is it possible to have different widgets on different pages,

I mean, I am having a form widget which has to be just displayed on posts page, it should just display on single.php

Is this possible? Is their any plugin for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@ntechi**:

Look at the plugin [**Widget Logic**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/).

Answer (score 2):

The [plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/) is called just like your Question title. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it manualy:
http://www.effutio.com/web-design/using-multipledifferent-headers-sidebars-footers-and-comment-templates-in-wordpress/193/

or use a plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/display-widgets/

Answer (score 1):

There are two options:

- Have a number of different sidebars in your theme. You will need to [register your sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar), and then [call the sidebar](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_sidebar) from one of your template files.
- Install a plugin such as Widget Logic.

You can also use a combination of these methods when you need to manage sets of widgets over a variety of different areas.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I may be wrong, but why can't you just create different sidebars for single and posts page? That's easier and doesn't require plugins.